# What is the entry point of an .xlam excel addin

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am doing some work on an excel addIn abc.xlam. 
This addIn is enabled in excel addIns.
I want to launch an .exe file whenever I open up a worksheet (new or existing) in excel.
I want to code this .exe launch part in the .xlam addIn at an event when a workbook is opened.
Please tell me how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I did it! 
I simply created a new function in an existing Macro

```
Private Sub MyMacro 
 MsgBox "HI" 
End Sub
```

And then, I called this function from ThisWorkbook

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 Run "MyMacro"
 Exit Sub
```

Comment: OK, great. If you move `MsgBox "HI"` to `Workbook_Open`, you have my example from the other answer. :) Now you need to trap the `NewWorkbook` event. Re-reading your question, you also need the `WorkbookOpen` event from the `Application` object in order to run code when both new and existing workbooks open. Worksheets probably have similar events - `WorkbookNewSheet` and `SheetActivate`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the `NewWorkbook` event of the Excel appliation, so you need to set a reference to the `Application` object when your addin loads.

Put the following example code in the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Option Explicit    '***** Always use Option Explicit!

Private WithEvents oXl As Application


Private Sub oXl_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    '***** Trapping the NewWorkbook event
    Call MsgBox("It's me again. (" & oXl.Workbooks.Count & ")", vbInformation, "Hi. Again.")

    '***** Your code here!
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    '***** Remove reference to oXL object
    Set oXl = Nothing
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    '***** Set reference to the current Excel application
    Set oXl = ThisWorkbook.Application

    '***** Testing the oXL object
    Call MsgBox("Hello, there! (" & oXl.Workbooks.Count & ")", vbInformation, "Hi")
End Sub
```

Comment: I dont know whats wrong with me these event never get hit ! Sorry I am a newbie to VBA

Comment: Have you loaded the addin? I get the `Workbook_Open` event right after I load the addin. The `NewWorkbook` event also works.

Comment: the addIn is loaded always. Like i dont have to load it everytime

Comment: OK, then you should get the `Workbook_Open` event when you start Excel. I had to unload the addin to make changes to it's VBA code (and reload it afterwards).

Comment: Workbook_Open does not hit as well. I put a message box on it, just to see if it is displayed everytime i open a workbook or not, it doesnt display !

Comment: @HamdaBinteAjmal did you put these macros in the `Workbook` code module or in a standard code module?  The latter will not work, and would be the most common reason why non of them "hit" for you.

Comment: @DavidZemens I put it inside abc.xlam > Microsoft excel Objects > ThisWorkbook

Comment: OK. Does the `Workbook_Open` event fire for abc.xlam?